# Spark request only a partial sorting for row_number().over partitioned window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Version: DBR 8.4 | Spark 3.1.2

I'm trying to get the top 500 rows per partition, but I can see from the query plan that it is sorting the entire data set (50K rows per partition) before eventually filtering to the rows I care about.

```py
  max_rank = 500
  ranking_order = Window.partitionBy(['category', 'id'])
    .orderBy(F.col('primary').desc(), F.col('secondary'))

  df_ranked = (df
    .withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(ranking_order))
    .where(F.col('rank') <= max_rank)
  )
  df_ranked.explain()
```

I read elsewhere that expressions such as `df.orderBy(desc("value")).limit(n)` are optimized by the query planner to use `TakeOrderedAndProject` and avoid sorting the entire table. Is there a similar approach I can use here to trigger an optimization and avoid fully sorting all partitions?

For context, right now my query is taking 3.5 hours on a beefy 4 worker x 40 core cluster and shuffle write time surrounding this query (including some projections not listed above) appears to be my high-nail, so I'm trying to cut down the amount of data as soon as possible.

Comment: Also worthy of a comment, while performing this query I got the hint: `Shuffle partition number too small: We recommend enabling Auto-Optimized Shuffle by setting 'spark.databricks.adaptive.autoOptimizeShuffle.enabled' to 'true' or changing 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' to 8582 or higher.` I added `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.adaptive.autoOptimizeShuffle.enabled", True)` and the hint went away, but it still appears to be using the default 200 partitions for everything ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯